# How can I render linkedIn profile json object properly, I have a good rough idea (react)

Tags: reactjs

React newbie here! I have a JSON object (linkedIn profile) and I am trying to put that data into the profile state, then deconstruct the profile object in the render function to nicely display each key-value item on the page.

componentDidMount:

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getProfile();
  }
```

getProfile() called from componentDidMount():

```js
 getProfile() {
    const profileObject = {
      firstName: {
        localized: {
          en_US: "Bob"
        },
        preferredLocale: {
          country: "US",
          language: "en"
        }
      },
      localizedFirstName: "Bob",
      headline: {
        localized: {
          en_US: "API Enthusiast at LinkedIn"
        },
        preferredLocale: {
          country: "US",
          language: "en"
        }
      },
      localizedHeadline: "API Enthusiast at LinkedIn",
      vanityName: "bsmith",
      id: "yrZCpj2Z12",
      lastName: {
        localized: {
          en_US: "Smith"
        },
        preferredLocale: {
          country: "US",
          language: "en"
        }
      },
      localizedLastName: "Smith",
      profilePicture: {
        displayImage: "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D00AAAAbBCDEFGhiJ"
      }
    };
    profile = profileObject
    // Transform data if needed
     this.setState({ profile });
  }
```

render() function:

```js
 render() {
    let { name, lastName, country } = { profile };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">News</h1>
        </header>
        <div className="App-feeds" />
        <div className="panel-list">
          <p>First Name: {name}</p>
          <p>Last Name: {lastName}</p>
          <p>Country: {country}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/profile-xtt86 - This is a demo of what I am trying to achieve.

```
{
"firstName":{
  "localized":{
     "en_US":"Bob"
  },
  "preferredLocale":{
     "country":"US",
     "language":"en"
  }
},
"localizedFirstName": "Bob",
"headline":{
  "localized":{
     "en_US":"API Enthusiast at LinkedIn"
  },
  "preferredLocale":{
     "country":"US",
     "language":"en"
  }
},......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to prepare your data before setting your state, something like:

```
// Transform data if needed
    this.setState({
      profile: {
        name: profileObject.localizedFirstName,
        lastName: profileObject.localizedLastName,
        country: profileObject.lastName.preferredLocale.country
      }
    });
```

Then destructure that in your render:

```
let { name, lastName, country } = this.state.profile;
```

Check it out here:

[image: Edit Profile]

I did notice that in your render function, you're not accessing the state, but a random profile variable.

```
  let { name, lastName, country } = { profile };
```

Remember, if you set your state and want to use something from your state, then call `this.state.{key}`, in your case, `this.state.profile`.

Comment: You are a god. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can fetch the data as a variable and set the state after that. What I mean:

```
const getData = async() => {
  const response = await fetch('path-to-json-file')
  const data = await response.json()
  this.setState({
    result: data
  })
}
```